# Arguments by case

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am taking real analysis, but that is really not important.....the important part is that my professor says that one of my methods of proof is invalid.

Essentially he is asking me to prove something of the form:

$$ X \iff Y $$

So basically I break the world into 2 cases: $A$ and $B$ (That is at least one of these is true and in fact only one is true)

I then prove the following:

$A\Rightarrow(X\iff Y)$

$B\Rightarrow(X\iff Y)$

Then I conclude:

$X\iff Y$

The problem my professor has is that my proof of $A\Rightarrow(X\iff Y)$ looks like this:

Assume $A$

...

$\therefore X \space and \space Y$

$\therefore X \iff Y$

And my proof of $B\Rightarrow(X\iff Y)$ is similar:

Assume $B$

...

$\therefore \tilde X \space and \space \tilde Y$

$\therefore X \iff Y$

My question is this......Is my method of proof valid, or am I missing something?

My professor's argument is with my statement that:

$ X \space and \space Y \Rightarrow (X \iff Y)$

He says, "Well you haven't shown that $X$ and $Y$ are related in any way"....his example of a counter example is:

Let $X=$ Milwaukee is by Lake Michigan and let $Y=$ All squares are rectangles....."Clearly" $X$ does not imply $Y$......

***Edit:***

Here is my theorem and proof:

Thm. $abs(a+b)=abs(a)+abs(b) \iff ab \ge 0$ where $abs(x)$ is the absolute value of $x$.

Proof:

There are four cases:

Case 1:

$$a\gt 0 \space and \space b\gt 0$$

Obviously $ab \ge 0$.

$$abs(a)=a \space and \space abs(b)=b$$

$$abs(a+b)=a+b$$

$$\therefore abs(a+b)=abs(a)+abs(b)$$

$$\therefore abs(a+b)=abs(a)+abs(b) \iff ab \ge 0$$

Case 2:

$$abs(a) < 0 \space and \space abs(b) < 0$$

Clearly $ab\ge 0$

$$abs(a)=-a$$

$$abs(b)=-b$$

$$-a-b=-(a+b)$$

But clearly $a+b\lt 0$

So

$$abs(a+b)=-a-b$$

$$\therefore abs(a+b)=abs(a)+abs(b)$$

$$\therefore abs(a+b)=abs(a)+abs(b) \iff ab \ge 0$$

Case 3:

$ a \gt 0 \space and \space b \lt 0$

Clearly $ab \lt 0$

$$abs(a)=a$$

$$abs(b)=-b$$

$$a-b=abs(a)+abs(b)$$

$$a+b=abs(a)-abs(b)$$

$$a-b\ne a+b \space and \space a-b\ne -a-b$$

$$\therefore abs(a+b)=abs(a)+abs(b)\iff ab\ge 0$$

$$\therefore abs(a+b)=abs(a)+abs(b)\iff ab\ge 0 \space in \space general$$

Case 4:

$a=0$

Clearly $ab\ge 0$ because it is zero.

By inspection we see:

$abs(b)=abs(b)$

$$\therefore abs(a+b)=abs(a)+abs(b)\iff ab\ge 0$$

$$\therefore abs(a+b)=abs(a)+abs(b)\iff ab\ge 0 \space in \space general$$

We technically have two more cases where in  3 and 4 we just swap $a$ and $b$ but those are symmetric and follow the same structure.

Comment: So, $A$ and $B$ are two statements from which we know that one of them must be true ?

Comment: @Peter Correct...

Comment: Then, your proof (although somewhat unusual) is perfectyl valid.

Comment: It seems valid. I have a feeling that you've written it in a confusing way, though. This is a very tricky argument to nail in a clear way.

Comment: Maybe it would help us if you present us the complete proof.

Comment: @Peter Completely agree. These analogies might miss the actual problem in the proof.

Comment: @Peter I have added my proof as requested....

Comment: @DonThousand ^^

Comment: In Case $1$ why don't you just mention $a+b\ge 0$ and therfore $|a+b|=a+b=|a|+|b|$ ?

Comment: @Peter Because I didn't think of that...

Comment: Showing $A \implies X$ and $Y$ is not $A\implies (X \iff Y)$.  It's $A \implies X$ and $Y$.  Likewise $B \implies (\lnot X$ and $\lnot Y)$ is an $B \implies (X \iff Y)$.  If $A$ and $B$ are exhaustive, though, then this proves $(X$ and $Y$) or ($\lnot X$ and $\lnot Y$)$ and that *is* $X\iff Y$.  (But only if $A$ or $B$ must be true.)

Comment: @fleablood https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence  If you look at property number 3 in the Logical equivalences involving biconditionals this is the property I am using

Comment: @Peter no it shows that $X\space and\space Y$ which implies $X\iff Y$

Comment: @DarthRubik Yor are right, I was too fast.

Comment: The cases $3)$ and $4)$ should contain $a\ge 0$ / $b\ge 0$, otherwise you miss the case $a=0$ and $b$ negative or vice versa.

Comment: @Peter I changed case 1 and added a new case in order to not miss this senario